# SignalR connection.on & connection.invoke

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have the following code

```
var connection = new signalR
        .HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("/bidHub")
        .build();

    connection.start().then(res => {
        connection.invoke("JoinGroup", auctionId)
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }).catch (function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });

ajax call here

connection.on("RefreshBids", function (currentBid, lastBidder) {
        document.getElementById("currentPrice").textContent = `$${currentBid}`;
        document.getElementById("lastBidder").textContent = `${lastBidder}`;
    });

    connection.invoke("RefreshBids", JSON.stringify(currentBid), JSON.stringify(lastBidder)).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
```

The code works with both 'connection.on' and with 'connection.on' + 'connection.invoke', but when they are both, 'connection.invoke' gives the error that it does not find 'currentBid' and 'lastBidder', it still works. It seems to work with 'connection.on', but should I use 'connection.invoke' as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage depends on if you are using a generated proxy. Generally you will use one or the other but not both. See [generated proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#how-to-call-server-methods-from-the-client) doc and [calling server methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#how-to-call-server-methods-from-the-client) doc for more details.